# What is this old time signature (2 with a vertical line through it)?

Tags: notation, time-signatures, baroque-period, meter

On the fourth line of page 5 of [the score of Fasch's Ouverture-Suite in F major](http://ks4.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/f/fa/IMSLP53989-PMLP111554-fasch_ov_suite_KF3.pdf), one reads a time signature that is the number 2 with a vertical line through it:

[image]

What does it mean? I know some 'standard' [old time signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_signature#Early_music_usage), but I have never seen this one.

Comment: Well, it looks like the first bar lasts for 5 beats and the rest - 4. The symbol looks like an odd combination of a 2 and a 4. It's familiar, but I don't remember how to interpret it.

Comment: @Pyromonk since it appears at the beginning and end of a part that should be repeated: could this be a predecessor of today's volta brackets?

Comment: @Pyromonk the first bar is four quarters long: 8th rest, 16th rest, 16th note, dotted 8th note, 16th note, dotted quarter note, 8th note.

Comment: @phoog, I meant the first bar after the mystical symbol, not the first bar of the piece.

Comment: @Pyromonk oh! That bar is actually a five-measure rest, so it's 20 quarters long (or ten half notes).

Comment: @phoog, yep, that's what I meant by 5 beats! It's quite mystical...

Comment: @Pyromonk but if you're counting quarter notes (which I presume you are because you say the rest of the piece has four beats per measure) then that "bar" is a 20-beat rest.  It's 5 *bars,* not 5 beats.

Comment: @phoog, I am officially confused. I have no idea what we're talking about (where in the piece each one of us is) and what mistake you think I am making.

Comment: @Pyromonk I'm talking about the notation `5.` just to the right of the red arrow in the picture included in the question, in the bottom-right corner.  That bar indicates 20 beats of rest, using two different methods.  The first is the number 5, meaning "this is a 5-measure rest," and the second is the two rests in the staff.  The first of those, between the second and fourth lines, is a [longa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longa_(music)) rest (worth four semibreves/whole notes) and the second is a semibreve/whole note rest, for a total of 20 beats.  Were you talking about a different spot?

Comment: @phoog, I was talking about the same spot, but I now see that we must have been using a different definition of "beat". How exactly do you define "beat"? I basically meant quarter notes. Thank you for using both the British and the American terms to clearly indicate your message.

Comment: @Pyromonk since it's not clear whether either section of the piece is in 2/2 or 4/4, I adopted your assumption that it's in 4, counting the quarter note (crotchet) as the beat.  If the section is in 2/2 then the rest is 10 beats long, counting half notes (minims).

Comment: @Pyromonk to put it another way, let's assume that a metronome is set to 120 quarter notes (or, equivalently, 60 half notes) each minute, so a single measure is 2 seconds.  Your comment seems to say that the bar in question is 2.5 seconds, but actually it is 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This should really be a comment, because I have no answer to the question.  But as I need to show  a picture...

Here's the bit following the strange time signature.  It continues in the same bar lengths.

[image]

(Also interesting to note the very literal G clefs.  A letter G on the second line.)

Comment: Is that cut 2/2 time or double cut time or some such thing? Is there such a thing?

Comment: Maybe it would be worth editing the question to insert the image there...

Comment: @David, take a look at the updates to my answer.  Still a bit of a mystery

Comment: @DavidBowling I suspect that the c-slash time is actually 4/4; it would be very unusual for a French overture to be in 2/2.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question.  I cannot explain the time signature, but I am certain that it *is* a time signature.  As evidence against the hypothesis that it is somehow a part of the repeat sign, note the last movement of the piece, which has repeats, but lacks the sign in question.

Note also the fact that the c-slash time signature is reintroduced at the end of the second section, which is why the unexplained time signature must be included after the final repeat sign as well as after the first repeat sign.  The reintroduction of c-slash can be seen on the second page of the first violin part, at the end of the tenth staff.  There is also a fermata on the first note of this measure, but it is difficult to see in this part because it is squeezed between the f' on that staff and the c''' on the staff below.

This is a natural manifestation of the [French overture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overture#French_overture) form, which typically begins with a slow stately section with dotted rhythms, followed by a faster fugato section.  Anyone familiar with Handel's overtures knows that there is normally a brief return to the stately tempo at the end of the movement; here the road map is slightly different, such that the fugato section is followed by a return to the stately material and is then repeated without returning to the stately material.

Back to the symbol in question, I would note that its form is rather different from that of the numeral *2* written at the top of the Violin 2, Oboe 2, and Horn 2 parts, as well as the 2/4 time signature of the Andante *Air.*  Of course, that doesn't exclude the possibility of the symbol in question nonetheless being derived from the numeral *2.*

From the context, then, we can infer that the symbol implies a faster tempo.  I suspect that the c-slash section is probably actually in 4/4, not 2/2, given the norms of the French overture form  (The standardization of c-slash to mean 2/2 came later; for example, in Bach's Mass in B minor, the second Kyrie is in c-slash meter but has four half notes per measure.)

The meaning of the c-slash time signature for measures with four quarter notes could perhaps be established with more certainty with more knowledge about when these parts were prepared and by whom, and with some comparative study of Fasch's other overtures.  If the stately section is indeed in a four-beat meter, it's reasonable to infer that the 2-slash means two beats per bar instead of four.

Comment: It is helpful if those who downvote explain what they think is wrong with the answer.

Comment: In the [Musescore](https://www.musescore.org) [time signatures](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/2/time-signatures) palette, the 2 with a line through it means Cut Time (Bach) which meant 2/2 in Bach's time. While transcribing Fasch's Overture-Suite in F major in Musescore from the edition in the body of the question, for every ¢ time signature in the manuscript, use 4/4 or C and for every 2-with-a-line-through-it time signature, use 2/2 or ¢ in Musescore. The 3 with a line through it in the time signatures palette means Cut Triple Time (9/8).

Answer (score 0):

## update number 2

I took a look at the following pages in the IMSLP link, and observed thattheree is a "repeat" sign at the end of the Overture followed by a "VS" indicator (and nothing else).

[image]

So now one wonders exactly what the " :||: "  marking indicates as well!  I'm leaning towards the  ":||: {slash2} " is an old way of indicating a repeat section, and nothing else.

Some digging...  [here](http://musicofyesterday.com/historical-music-theory/expanded-history-musical-notation-part-3/)

> The general principles of ancient time signatures are that three
> strokes or a circle or the figure 3 denote perfections, or ternary
> divisions, and two strokes, or a semicircle, or the figure 2 denote
> imperfection or binary division. A line drawn through a circle or
> semicircle, or the inversion of these figures, shows diminution of the
> value of the notes to the extent of one half, so that longs are to be
> sung as if they were breves, breves as if they were semibreves, etc.

Without seeing the following measures, can't tell if that slash thru the "2" is stylistic or some oddball hack.

### previous info, where I looked at the top of the image --

It looks to me like the standard "Cut Time" notation, indicating 2/2.

quoting the online [Dolmetsch](https://www.dolmetsch.com/musicalsymbols.htm) (which everyone should bookmark),

> alla breve: also called 'cut time' or 'alla cappella time'; marked
> with a large C with a vertical line through it, used for quick duple
> time in which the minim or half note is given one beat instead of two.
> (occasionally written with two parallel vertical lines through a large
> C)

Comment: But the piece was already in cut time. I am wondering if this is indicating 2/4 time. The marking looks like a stylized 2/4.

Comment: Oh, --- I see you mean that bit at the end of the image.  How about you post an image of the measures **following** that  slash-2 so we can see what is written?

Comment: Oh dear this does make me feel old.  I recall learning this at school. As @Carl Witthoft says this is Alla Breve or 2/2.  A big "C" was shorthand for common time  (4/4) whereas a big "C" with a line through it was shorthand for Alla Breve or 2/2 time.

Comment: @JimM -- you have to look all the way at the end of the last line of the posted image to see that OP isn't talking about the cut time that the piece starts in, but about a clear "2" with a cut line through it.

Comment: Whoops.  My bad.  Still feel old though.

Comment: The sign is certainly a time signature.  It is used at the final repeat because c-slash time is reintroduced in the middle of the second section.  Also note that the repeats in the final movement lack this sign.  See [my answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/74757/2257) for more detail.

Comment: @DavidBowling there's another movement in 2/4 time and the sign looks nothing like this one (and very much like a 2 over a 4).  There are also 4 quarters per measure here rather than 2.

Comment: @phoog -- when I was pondering 2/4, the post did not show subsequent measures. Unless this music departs from conventional notation, it begins in cut time (2/2). The symbol in question (the 2 with a cut through it) could indicate cut 2/2 time (i.e., 1/1, or perhaps double cut time). I have never seen this before, but it would be consistent with conventional usage of the cut-line and the subsequent 4 quarter notes per bar supports this interpretation. That is what my later comment was attempting to suggest.

Comment: @DavidBowling The first link in the question points to a PDF containing the entire set of parts for all three movements.  The c-slash is already weird, as I noted in my answer, since the opening of a French overture would normally be in 4/4, though it might be possible to do this as a very slow 2/2.  Playing the fast section in 1/1 is seriously unlikely to work, however.  Unfortunately, Fasch has a huge body of work available on imslp, so going through all the manuscripts to seek other instances of this symbol would be very time consuming.